# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_Animal__animal_available'

Tags: python, class, object

I am working on an assignment for class, and get the following AttributeError:

```
    File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Python\******PetStore\Animal.py", line 24, in get_available
    self.__animal_available = 'available'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_Animal__animal_available'
```

The assignment is to create program simulating a Pet Store. The program has to create animal with a name, and whether it is available. Whenever after setting the animal available I get the error above. Here is a snippet of the main program.

```
   elif menu_input == '1':
        type = input("What type of animal would you like to create? ")
        name = input("What is the animal’s name? ")
        available = input('Is the animal available for adoption y/n? ')
        Animal.Animal.get_available(available, available)
```

Now here is the Animal class where the error is thrown.

```
import random

class Animal:

    def __init__(self, animal_type, animal_name, available):
        self.__animal_name = animal_name
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.set_mood()
        self.get_available()

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__animal_name

    def check_mood(self):
        return self.__mood

    def get_available(self, available):
        if available != 'y':
            self.__animal_available = 'not available'
        else:
            self.__animal_available = 'available'
        return self.__animal_available

    def set_mood(self):
        random_number = random.randint(1,3)
        if(1 == random_number):
            self.__mood = "happy"
        if(2 == random_number):
            self.__mood = "hungry"
        if(3 == random_number):
            self.__mood = "sleepy"
```

Comment: That's not a class that's a method. Could you please show the **_class_**?

Comment: Firstly, share the content of the class. also, why you have `Animal.Animal` twice in your code?

Comment: Added the entire class. I have animal twice because I got an AttributeError saying get_available is not define when I just do Animal.get_available(available)

Comment: Normal use would be something like `Animal.Animal(type, name, available).get_available()`

Comment: Why are you invoking `__name_mangling`? To put it another way, where did you get the idea that `__two_leading_underscores` was a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Animal` and then call the `get_available` method on *that*.  e.g.:

```
animal_instance = Animal.Animal(type, name, available)
print(animal_instance.get_available())
```

Of course, you can do this without the intermediate variable to hold the instance:

```
print(Animal.Animal(type, name, available).get_available())
```

---

What you're doing is calling the method as if it were a static method.  Since you pass `available` twice, you're basically setting `self` inside the method to `available` (which is a string) and that explains the error that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem!